# Jupyter notebook doesn't launch

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I am trying to launch `jupyter notebook` from Anaconda prompt but it does not launch and there isn't any error in command prompt either. However, `jupyter lab` works ok and I am able to run notebooks.

[image]

Comment: What's the server prompt saying?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps:

1. `conda update conda`
2. `conda update anaconda-navigator`
3. `conda update navigator-updater`

and try again.